# neither gdm3 nor lightdm nor startx work

Tags: lightdm

After the update to 18.04, gdm3 was stuck on "started gnome display manager" so after looking on internet I tried a lot of things : repair packages with recovery mode, same, and then reinstall gdm3 with a console (Ctrl+alt+F2). After that the login screen appeared but I had to enter 2 times my password to.. have then a black screen. And now after some reboot, each time I enter the password, that ignores it and go back to the login screen again : http://image.noelshack.com/fichiers/2018/18/7/1525607498-img-0658.jpg

I tried to install lightdm and to start it directly (sudo lightdm) or to "boot" with : (sudo dkgp-reconfigure lightdm and then reboot) but all I obtain from lightdm is.. a black screen with a white prompt: http://image.noelshack.com/fichiers/2018/18/7/1525607504-img-0664.jpg

When I try to do startx from a console : https://image.noelshack.com/minis/2018/18/7/1525607503-sanazs-titare.png + https://image.noelshack.com/minis/2018/18/7/1525607500-img-0657.png

What should I do ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved by installing nvidia drivers (sudo apt-get install nvidia-352)

Comment: Thanks for sharing your solution. Please 'accept' your solution in order to show people that there is a good solution to your problem.

Comment: ^^^ What he said only you might have to wait 2 days before the software allows you to do so.